# How can I load a Perl module at runtime?

Tags: perl, installation, module

I would like to use the HTML::Template module.  However, it is not installed on the server I'm using to develop CGI scripts.

Is it possible to load a module at runtime:  I found the Template.pm file on my local Perl installation and uploaded the file to the server I'm using.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use CGI qw(:standard :html4);
use CGI::Carp qw(warningsToBrowser fatalsToBrowser);

# use HTML::Template;

use Template;

# my $package = "HTML::Template";
# eval {
# (my $pkg = $package) =~ s|::|/|g; # require need a path
# require "$pkg.pm";
# import $package;
# };
# die $@ if( $@ );

# open the HTML template
my $template = HTML::Template->new(filename => 'test.tmpl');

# fill in some parameters in the template
$template->param(home => $ENV{HOME});
$template->param(path => $ENV{PATH});

# send the obligatory Content-Type
print "Content-Type: text/html\n\n";

# print the template
print $template->output;
```

Comment: I'm confused. If you've uploaded Template.pm to your server, you should be able to load it at compile time with 'use'?

Comment: I'm getting an error on the line:

my $template = HTML::Template->new(filename => 'test.tmpl');

Comment: @coson And, what is the error?

Comment: You have to uncomment the line "use HTML::Template" and comment out "use Template"

Comment: Can't locate object method "new" via package "HTML::Template" (perhaps you forgot to load "HTML::Template"?) at testtemplate.pl line 20.

The other thing is I have a Template.pm and four HTTP.pm in my Perl Windows installation and am not sure which one I should use for the HTML::Template module

Comment: Is the Template.pm you found part of HTML::Template or some other templating system?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is what I do:

```
     cgi-bin/script.pl
     cgi-bin/lib/HTML/Template.pm
```

In `script.pl` (unless you are running under `mod_perl`):

```
 use FindBin qw( $Bin );
 use File::Spec::Functions qw( catfile );
 use lib catfile $Bin, 'lib';
 use HTML::Template;

 # The rest of your script
```

If [HTML::Template](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/HTML::Template) is truly optional, read [perldoc -f require](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/require.html).

See also [How do I keep my own module/library directory?](http://faq.perl.org/perlfaq8.html#How_do_I_keep_my_own) and [What's the difference between require and use?](http://faq.perl.org/perlfaq8.html#What_s_the_differenc) in [perlfaq8](http://faq.perl.org/perlfaq8.html).

Comment: Yeah, this looks like what you actually want to do, just add another place for modules that perl knows to look for, which is what the `use lib ...` line is doing (the two lines above it are about finding the modules location relative to the script)

Answer (score 9):

This is similar to Sinan's answer, but uses [local::lib](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/local::lib):

Set up your files as:

```
cgi-bin/script.pl
cgi-bin/lib/HTML/Template.pm
```

And in your script:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use local::lib 'lib';
use HTML::Parser;
```

The advantage of local::lib is you can install modules from CPAN directly into a directory of your choosing:

```
perl -MCPAN -Mlocal::lib=lib -e 'CPAN::install("HTML::Parser")'
```

Comment: +1 Useful for when you just want to use extra modules from user directory while debugging some cgi-bin server scripts.

Answer (score 4):

[HTML::Template](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?HTML::Template) and [Template](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Template-Toolkit/) are different Perl modules. If you want to use HTML::Template, you will need to `use HTML::Template;` at the top of the script to import that package.

Ensure that you copied the HTML/Template.pm file from your local machine to the server, rather than Template.pm.

Comment: The problem is I don't know which is the correct HTML::Template module.  When I search under my Windows installation, I see four HTML.pm and a Template.pm.  I'm not sure which one I'm supposed to use.  I'm sure that I could try this out one file at a time.

Comment: It will be called Template.pm but will be inside a directory called HTML. This is how Perl modules are laid out, e.g. Moose::Meta::Class is in Moose/Meta/Class.pm

Comment: yeah, I finally figured that out based on the previous answer.

Answer (score 1):

I should have added this as an option, since I'm one of the maintainers of this module:  [App::FatPacker](http://metacpan.org/module/App%3a%3aFatPacker) can be used to include a third-party module with your application when it ships, so it does not need to be installed separately in the deployment environment.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is. Look at [Module::Runtime](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Module::Runtime). I would install your HTML module though, even in a local install directory. It's probably less hassle.

Comment: Do you mean FTP the Template.pm to the local install directory on the server?